# Upper bound on the number of ways to completely fill boxes.

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, asymptotics

I have $x$ indistinguishable items and $n$ boxes with sizes $y_1,\dots,y_n$. I am interested in the number of ways of allocating those $x$ items into the boxes such that all boxes must be either fully filled (i.e., the number of items in each box equals its size) or empty. Also, I have the condition $x=o(n)$ (where $x\leq n/2$ is included in the condition), which indicate that boxes of smaller sizes might possibly lead to more number of ways.

For example, if I have 3 items and 100 boxes all with size 2, then I have 0 ways to achieve my goal. However, if one of the boxes have size 3, then I would have one way to achieve my goal. If I have 3 items and 100 boxes all with size 1, then I have ${100\choose 3}$ ways to achieve my goal.

I suspect that the upper bound for the number of ways of allocating those $x$ items into $n$ boxes such that all boxes must be fully filled is ${n\choose x}$, which is the case where all boxes have size 1. I'm having trouble arguing this rigorously. Is there a way to show this rigorously or is the claim wrong?

Comment: The sets $S\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ such that $\sum_{j\in S} y_j= x$ form an anti-chain, so you might use this inequality. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality

Comment: I don't quite see how to use it as the binomial coefficient is inside the summation for the inequality you suggested. I would appreciate it if you could show me how, thanks.

Comment: For example, If $y_1\leq y_2\leq \cdot\leq y_n,$ and for some $k\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^{k} y_i\geq x$ the we can use my linked inequality to show that the maximum can be $\binom n k.$

Comment: In particular, if $x\leq n/2,$ you get a maximum or $\binom n x.$

Comment: Why does $k\leq\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ imply $\sum_{i=1}^ky_i\geq x$? Did you mean to say $k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$? Can you explain how $y_i$'s here (size of box $i$) connect with the $a_k$'s (sets of size $k$ in the family $A$) in your linked inequality? You can also create an answer if it is easier for exposition. Thanks.

Comment: I meant of $k$ satisfied $\sum_{j=1}^k y_j\\geq x$ and $k\leq n/2$ then the maximum is $\binom n k.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to flesh out the details of the proof alluded to in the comments:

Let $\mathcal A$ be the collection of $S$ for which $\sum_{i\in S}y_i=x$. Then $\mathcal A$ is an antichain in the poset of subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. Let $a_k$ be the number of subsets of size $k$ in $\mathcal A$.
The [LYM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality) implies
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{a_k}{\binom{n}k}\le 1.\tag{*}
$$
Therefore,
$$
|\mathcal A|
= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k
\stackrel{1}=\sum_{k=0}^{x}a_k
= \binom{n}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a_k}{\binom{n}x}
\stackrel{2}\le \binom{n}{x}\sum_{k=0}^{x}\frac{a_k}{\binom{n}k}
\stackrel{*}\le \binom{n}x\cdot 1.
$$

1. We must have $a_k=0$ for $k>x$, since if there were more then $x$ full boxes, the total number of items would be more than $x$.
2. Here, we use the fact that $x<n/2$, so that $\binom{n}k\le \binom{n}x$ for all $k\le x$.

Comment: Big help, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A generating function argument is that the number of ways of doing this is the coefficient of $z^x$ in the expansion of $\left(1+z^{y_1}\right)\left(1+z^{y_2}\right)\left(1+z^{y_3}\right)\cdots \left(1+z^{y_n}\right)$

That is certainly less than or equal to the coefficient of $z^x$ in the expansion of $\left(1+z\right)^{\sum y_i}$, which is ${\sum y_i \choose x}$, but you have in effect asked if it is always less than or equal to the coefficient of $z^x$ in the expansion of $\left(1+z\right)^{n}$, which is ${n \choose  x}$.

The answer to that could clearly be no in some cases even when $x<n$.  For example if $n=10$ and $x=8$ and each $y_i=2$ then there are ${10 \choose 4}= 210$ possibilities in the box size $2$ case and ${10 \choose 8}= 45$ possibilities in the box size $1$ case.

So it may come down to precisely what you mean by $x=o(n)$.

Comment: For $x=o(n)$, I am more of considering cases of very large $n$ where $n$ is much larger than $x$. So for example, when $n=1000$ and $x=n/(\log n)\approx 144$. So is it safe to assume that the inequality holds for very large values of $n$ (where $x\ll n$ )? In other words, asymptotically, the inequality should hold?

Comment: @User It would not surprise me if your suggestion was always true when $x \le \frac n2$

Comment: Right, thanks. But then, I would need a different proof (from the one you answered) to show that my suspected inequality holds for $x\leq n/2$?

Comment: @User I suspect there is a generating function approach to a proof  when $x \le \frac n2$  but my intuition would be that in Pascal's triangle, being further down and closer to the middle makes the numbers larger

Comment: Yes, if $x\leq n/2$ we have that $\binom n x$ is an upper bound.